# Delay transition of a button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to transition a button in a SwiftUI project such that, when the button is pressed, it will do a `.move(edge: .trailing)` and after approximately a half a second a different image for the button will come into view.

Here's what I have so far and as expected the image changes simultaneously. I'm curious if this is something that can be accomplished with asymmetric transitions. Trying to avoid using two different buttons that have animating offsets changing.

```
@State var delayedMove = false

@ViewBuilder
var moveMe: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                delayedMove.toggle()
            }
        }) {
            if delayedMove {
                selectImageButton
                    .animation(.linear.delay(delayedMove ? 0 : 1))
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            } else {
                deleteImage
                    .animation(.linear.delay(!delayedMove ? 0 : 1))
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. I just split up the single `if`-`else` into 2 `if`s, wrapped in a `ZStack`.

The button also makes `secondaryDelay` equal `true` for half a second, and then it switches back to `false`.

When the view leaves the hierarchy, that's when the transition starts. I worked out the way to do this by considering all the scenarios for the `selectImageButton`:

- **Showing** - show: delayedMove = true, secondaryDelay = false
- **Starting to hide** - hide: delayedMove = false, secondaryDelay = true
- **Hiding** - hide: delayedMove = false, secondaryDelay = false
- **Starting to show** - hide: delayedMove = true, secondaryDelay = true

From above, we only need to show when `delayedMove && !secondaryDelay` equals `true`. Similar method for other `deleteImage`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var delayedMove = false
    @State var secondaryDelay = false

    var body: some View {
        moveMe
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var moveMe: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    delayedMove.toggle()
                    secondaryDelay = true

                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        secondaryDelay = false
                    }
                }
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    if delayedMove && !secondaryDelay {
                        selectImageButton
                            .animation(.linear)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    }

                    if !delayedMove && !secondaryDelay {
                        deleteImage
                            .animation(.linear)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: @KelbyMittan I amended the code as the `.delay` modifier is now redundant. You will no longer need that in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `asymmetric`, and no need to repeat the code. But `Transition` in SwiftUI needs 2 things to works correctly first a `Group` and Second an `if & else`, it is how it works right now maybe in future it changes but you can see the Code:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var toggleButton = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Button("Toggle Button") { toggleButton.toggle() }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: { toggleButton.toggle() }, label: {
                
                Group {
                    
                    if toggleButton {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing), removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)))
                
            })
            
        }
        .padding()
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.5), value: toggleButton)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response... This is kind of the idea I've been playing with, I guess what I can't quite figure out is how or where to implement a delay so that the trash bin doesn't start to transition or animate into view until the plus symbol is gone. It seems they both happen simultaneously.

Comment: Frankly I did not understand about `simultaneously` in your question I worked on `asymmetric`

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying that better, I should have probably included a gif or screen shot.

Comment: No issue, it was interesting problem to trying to solve. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the same button and have the label animated with an offset if you want a clean and smooth animation like the first image going out and the other entering. you can try this view

```
@State var delayedMove = false
var moveMe: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation (.linear(duration: 0.5)){
                    delayedMove.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                ZStack{
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .offset(x: delayedMove ? 0 : 200)
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .offset(x: delayedMove ? 200 : 0)
                }
                .imageScale(.large)
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
    }
```